# Scala 3 Manifest replacement

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

My task is to print out type information in Java-like notation (using `<`, `>` for type arguments notation). In scala 2 I have this small method using `scala.reflect.Manifest` as a source for type symbol and it's parameters:

```
def typeOf[T](implicit manifest: Manifest[T]): String = {
  def loop[T0](m: Manifest[T0]): String =
    if (m.typeArguments.isEmpty) m.runtimeClass.getSimpleName
    else {
      val typeArguments = m.typeArguments.map(loop(_)).mkString(",")
      raw"""${m.runtimeClass.getSimpleName}<$typeArguments>"""
    }
  loop(manifest)
}
```

Unfortunately in Scala 3 Manifests are not available. Is there a Scala 3 native way to rewrite this? I'm open to some inline macro stuff. What I have tried so far is

```
inline def typeOf[T]: String = ${typeOfImpl}

private def typeOfImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[String] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val tree = TypeTree.of[T]
  tree.show 
  //    ^^ call is parameterized with Printer but AFAIK there's no way
  //       to provide your own implementation for it. You can to chose
  //       from predefined ones. So how do I proceed from here?
```

I know that Scala types can't be all represented as Java types. I aim to cover only simple ones that the original method was able to cover. No wildcards or existentials, only fully resolved types like:

- `List[String]` res: `List<String>`
- `List[Option[String]]` res: `List<Option<String>>`
- `Map[String,Option[Int]]` res: `Map<String,Option<Int>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final working solution I came up with was:

```
def typeOfImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[String] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  TypeRepr.of[T] match {
    case AppliedType(tpr, args) =>
      val typeName   = Expr(tpr.show)
      val typeArguments = Expr.ofList(args.map {
        _.asType match {
          case '[t] => typeOfImpl[t]
        }
      })
      '{
        val tpeName = ${ typeName }
        val typeArgs  = ${ typeArguments }
        typeArgs.mkString(tpeName + "<", ", ", ">")
      }
    case tpr: TypeRef => Expr(tpr.show)
    case other =>
        report.errorAndAbort(s"unsupported type: ${other.show}", Position.ofMacroExpansion)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*I post this answer even though it's not a definitive solution and there's probably a better way but hopefully it can give you some ideas.*

I think a good start is using `TypeRepr`:

```scala
val tpr: TypeRepr = TypeRepr.of[T]
val typeParams: List[TypeRepr] = tpr match {
  case a: AppliedType => a.args
  case _              => Nil
}
```

Then with a recursive method you should be able to work something out.

---

Copied from Inspired from https://github.com/gaeljw/typetrees/blob/main/src/main/scala/io/github/gaeljw/typetrees/TypeTreeTagMacros.scala#L12:

```scala
private def getTypeString[T](using Type[T], Quotes): Expr[String] = {
  import quotes.reflect._

  def getTypeStringRec(tpr: TypeRepr)(using Quotes): Expr[String] = {
    tpr.asType match {
      case '[t] => getTypeString[t]
    }
  }

  val tpr: TypeRepr = TypeRepr.of[T]
  val typeParams: List[TypeRepr] = tpr match {
    case a: AppliedType => a.args
    case _              => Nil
  }

  val selfTag: Expr[ClassTag[T]] = getClassTag[T]
  val argsStrings: Expr[List[String]] =
    Expr.ofList(typeParams.map(getTypeStringRec))

  '{ /* Compute something using selfTag and argsStrings */ }
}

private def getClassTag[T](using Type[T], Quotes): Expr[ClassTag[T]] = {
  import quotes.reflect._

  Expr.summon[ClassTag[T]] match {
    case Some(ct) =>
      ct
    case None =>
      report.error(
        s"Unable to find a ClassTag for type ${Type.show[T]}",
        Position.ofMacroExpansion
      )
      throw new Exception("Error when applying macro")
  }

}
```