# Scala 3 Macro - Retain a generic type in runtime

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm looking for an option to retain a generic type in runtime in Scala3. In Scala2 there was a TypeTag for this, however, now it is removed and the suggested option is to use macros (https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-and-reflection/3627).

The documentation, however, is somewhat cryptic...

This is what I'm trying to do:

Here's a macro implementation:

```
object TestMacroImpl {
  def getClassImpl[T](using Quotes)(using t: Type[T]): Expr[Class[T]] = '{
    classOf[${t}]
  }
}
```

Here's a macro:

```
import macros.TestMacro.getClassMacro

class TypedBox[T] {
  val staticClass: Class[T] = TypedBox.getStaticClass[T]
}

object TypedBox {
  inline def getStaticClass[T] = ${ getClassMacro[T] }
}
```

Test:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val stringBox = TypedBox[String]()
    println(stringBox.staticClass)
  }
}
```

I would envision this to be resolved as `val staticClass = classOf[String]`

But this does not compile, I'm getting:

```
/workspace/macros-test/src/main/scala/macros/TestMacro.scala:7:13
t.Underlying is not a class type
    classOf[${t}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Look also at https://github.com/zio/izumi-reflect and `shapeless3.typeable.Typeable` https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3/tree/main/modules/typeable/src/main/scala/shapeless3/typeable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071848/scala-3-manifest-replacement

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/oouaz9/any_signs_of_runtime_reflection_in_scala3/

Comment: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-and-reflection/3627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why but I don't think you can reliably get an `Expr[Class[T]]` out of macros (from what I understood, it could be that the `Class` does not yet exist at the time of macro execution).

Plus, a `Class[T]` does not retain the parameterized types: `classOf[Map [String, String]] = classOf[Map[Int, Int]]` for instance.

If you don't care about them, I'd use a `ClassTag` instead of `TypeTag` which is still available in Scala 3. And no need for macros.

By the way, in macros, you can write something like the following to get a `Expr[ClassTag[T]]`:

```scala
private def getClassTag[T](using Type[T], Quotes): Expr[ClassTag[T]] = {
    import quotes.reflect._

    Expr.summon[ClassTag[T]] match {
      case Some(ct) =>
        ct
      case None =>
        report.error(
          s"Unable to find a ClassTag for type ${Type.show[T]}",
          Position.ofMacroExpansion
        )
        throw new Exception("Error when applying macro")
    }

  }
```

*Finally, you might find some useful things at https://github.com/gaeljw/typetrees/blob/main/src/main/scala/io/github/gaeljw/typetrees/TypeTreeTagMacros.scala#L8 (disclaimer: I wrote it for personal projects).*

Comment: Thanks, Gaёl! Yeah, I know it doesn't retain parameter types, just needed to start from somewhere... 

This macro works. I'd like a class field `val staticClass: T`, populated by an inline method, but that's doesn't seem to be possible, as T is not known. Had to use the macro from outside of the class.
And weirdly, I get compilation errors on `import quotes.reflect._` and `report.error`. Only removing them helps. I use scala 3.0.2.

Anyway, you gave me a good path forward, thank you so much!

Also, you have a nice library, looks almost like exactly what I needed!