# Is it possible to match a quoted type of a sum type?

Tags: scala, enums, scala-macros, scala-3

I am doing type class derivation in Scala3.
My typeclass is `BarOf[T]` extending `Bar`. `T` is expected to be an ADT.
`Bar` has a `children` method returning the `BarOf[X]` of the children types of T.

Here the `derived` method is based on `Quotes` rather than on `Mirror`s. This is needed for the rest of my code, which has been removed here.

The essential step to find out the `BarOf[X]` (for each of the `X` children types)  is based on a *quoted type match*. (Full code at the end of the post)

```
A.memberType(childSymbol).asType match {
        case '[f] => Expr.summon[BarOf[f]]
      }
```

This works fine for *product types*  and particularly case classes.
But, when applying to *sum types*, the compiler fires an assertion :

```
assertion failure for class C1 <:< f, frozen = false
6 |sealed class Foo1 derives BarOf
  |                         ^
  |Exception occurred while executing macro expansion.
  |java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: ClassInfo(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)), class C0, List(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),class Foo)))
  |     at scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:8)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$TypeBounds.<init>(Types.scala:4918)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$RealTypeBounds.<init>(Types.scala:4994)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$TypeBounds$.apply(Types.scala:5038)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$TypeBounds.derivedTypeBounds(Types.scala:4926)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ConstraintHandling.addOneBound(ConstraintHandling.scala:116)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ConstraintHandling.addOneBound$(ConstraintHandling.scala:27)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ProperGadtConstraint.addOneBound(GadtConstraint.scala:60)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ConstraintHandling.addBoundTransitively(ConstraintHandling.scala:170)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ConstraintHandling.addBoundTransitively$(ConstraintHandling.scala:27)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ProperGadtConstraint.addBoundTransitively(GadtConstraint.scala:60)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.ProperGadtConstraint.addBound(GadtConstraint.scala:159)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.gadtAddLowerBound(TypeComparer.scala:118)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.narrowGADTBounds(TypeComparer.scala:1913)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.compareGADT$1(TypeComparer.scala:521)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.thirdTryNamed$1(TypeComparer.scala:524)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.thirdTry$1(TypeComparer.scala:573)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.secondTry$1(TypeComparer.scala:504)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.compareNamed$1(TypeComparer.scala:313)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.firstTry$1(TypeComparer.scala:319)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.recur(TypeComparer.scala:1321)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.isSubType(TypeComparer.scala:201)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.isSubType(TypeComparer.scala:211)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer.topLevelSubType(TypeComparer.scala:128)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.TypeComparer$.topLevelSubType(TypeComparer.scala:2729)
  |     at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:1035)
  |     at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuoteMatcher$.$eq$qmark$eq(QuoteMatcher.scala:336)
  |     at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuoteMatcher$.treeMatch(QuoteMatcher.scala:129)
  |     at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl.scala$quoted$runtime$impl$QuotesImpl$$treeMatch(QuotesImpl.scala:3021)
  |     at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$TypeMatch$.unapply(QuotesImpl.scala:2991)
  |     at bar.BarOf$.childExpr$1(bar.scala:21)
  |     at bar.BarOf$.$anonfun$6(bar.scala:26)
  |     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
  |     at bar.BarOf$.derivedImpl(bar.scala:26)
```

The assertion is triggered by the quoted type match : `case '[f] =>`. But I cannot figure out what I am missing.
Is my code legal ?

- if no  : what is the alternative ?
- if yes : is it compiler bug ?

Full `bar` package source:

```
package bar
import scala.quoted.*


trait Bar:
  def children : List[Bar]

trait BarOf[A] extends Bar

object BarOf :
  inline def derived[A]: BarOf[A] =  ${derivedImpl[A]}

  def derivedImpl[A:Type](using Quotes):Expr[BarOf[A]] =
    import quotes.reflect._
    val A           = TypeRepr.of[A]
    val mySymbol    = A.typeSymbol
    val terms       = mySymbol.children

    def childExpr(childSymbol:Symbol) =
      A.memberType(childSymbol).asType match {
        case '[f] => Expr.summon[BarOf[f]]
      } getOrElse {
        report.errorAndAbort(s"ChildType ${childSymbol} of ${mySymbol} does not derive BarOf")
      }

    val termsExpr =  Expr.ofList(terms.map(childExpr))
    '{  new BarOf[A]
        {   def children = ${termsExpr}
        }
     }
```

Test Code:

```
import bar.BarOf
  
// works
enum Foo0 derives BarOf :
  case C0

// does not work 
enum Foo1 derives BarOf :
  case C1(x:Int)

// does not work either :
sealed class Foo2 derives BarOf
class C2(x:Int) extends Foo2



@main def run:Unit =
  val x = summon[BarOf[Foo1]]
  println(x.children)
```

Comment: compiler told me to use curly braces on Symbol literals, but your example of `'[..]` worked for me, thanks for posting!

Comment: as an alternative, have you tried getting type information using?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69073868/1080804. I use that approach and if is unable to identify a type I fallback to matching Symbol literals like you are doing. Matching literals is tricky though if you don't know every possibility prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not in the type pattern matching as I thought, but on the symbol being matched.

The correct look-up is :

```
childSymbol.typeRef.asType match {
    case '[f] => Expr.summon[BarOf[f]]
}
```

instead of :

```
A.memberType(childSymbol).asType match {
    case '[f] => Expr.summon[BarOf[f]]
}
```

Complete Functional Code :

```
package bar
import scala.quoted.*


trait Bar:
  def children : List[Bar]

trait BarOf[A] extends Bar

object BarOf :
  inline def derived[A]: BarOf[A] =  ${derivedImpl[A]}

  def derivedImpl[A:Type](using Quotes):Expr[BarOf[A]] =
    import quotes.reflect._
    val A           = TypeRepr.of[A]
    val mySymbol    = A.typeSymbol
    val terms       = mySymbol.children

    def childExpr(childSymbol:Symbol) =
      childSymbol.typeRef.asType match {
        case '[f] => Expr.summon[BarOf[f]]
      } getOrElse {
        report.errorAndAbort(s"ChildType ${childSymbol} of ${mySymbol} does not derive BarOf")
      }

    val termsExpr =  Expr.ofList(terms.map(childExpr))
    '{  new BarOf[A]
        {   def children = ${termsExpr}
            override def toString = ${Expr(s"BarOf[${mySymbol.fullName}]")}
        }
     }
```